# User Field Update when user Login

Tags: salesforce-classic, admin

is there any way in salesforce to update a User field when User logs in without coding?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `login flows` and update user from flows (no code involved).

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow.htm&type=5

For eg, updating a user record when user logs in , just an example.

[image]

[image]

Or you can use a proper screen flow with messages to show a welcome screen so that does not look blank.

But there is a catch, login flows can only get triggered when user logs in via Salesforce UI. It wont work if you are using this user to use it as an integration user.

**NOTE:** Also keep in mind that login flow works only on profile level and not for specific user. So if a login flow is activated for a specific profile, all the users under this profile will have to go through this flow.